# Linking problem when compiling from source

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there!

I'm not sure what's going on, but when compiling Gazebo from source (default), the gazebo executable is missing some shared libraries.

```
$ gazebo
    gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_common.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ ldd /usr/local/bin/gazebo
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdcd04000)
    libgazebo_common.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_util.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_sdf_interface.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_transport.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_physics.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_sensors.so.1 => not found
    libgazebo_msgs.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb95ff5a000)
    libtbb.so.2 => /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007fb95fd2c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb95fb28000)
    libprotobuf.so.7 => /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.7 (0x00007fb95f839000)
    libgazebo_math.so.1 => not found
    libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 (0x00007fb95f61f000)
    libboost_system.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 (0x00007fb95f41b000)
    libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1 (0x00007fb95f1b5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb95eeb5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb95ec9f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb95e8df000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb9601ac000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb95e6c8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb95e3cc000)
```

I can get Gazebo running after adding `/usr/local/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I have the feeling, that shouldn't be necessary.

Any idea what's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3189/linking-problem-when-compiling-from-source/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 129 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to [ldconfig(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

> **ldconfig** creates the necessary links
> and cache to the most recent shared
> libraries found in the directories
> specified on the command line, in the
> file */etc/ld.so.conf*, and in the
> trusted directories (*/lib* and
> */usr/lib*)

Also on Ubuntu there are no configuration files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` for such location as `/usr/local/lib`, thus it has to be added manually in order dynamic linker to find appropriate libraries.

So, seems there is nothing wrong :)

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-06-13**:
OK, I went over the [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install#Compiling_From_Source) again and saw that it is actually listed. However, it is missing when using the default. I may just be a matter of correcting those instructions. Thanks for your help!